Expected number of edges to draw in a bipartite graph until you get a crossing
I was asked by a friend to calculate the number of edge crossings in a $m \times n$ complete bipartite graph:


 ${m\choose 2}{n \choose 2}$ crossings (since if we choose 2 vertices on the left, 2 vertices on the right, there is exactly one pair of edges which will cross and one which won't, and this is bijective to the total number of edges. Another method of solving is by induction by counting the new number of crossings introduced each time we add a node $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$)

Now play a game where you randomly select an edge with equal probability each turn: what is the expected # of turns until you get a crossing?
Let $N=$ number of turns until you get a crossing. Then $\mathbb{E}(N)=\sum_{k=2}^{mn} kP(N=k)=\sum_{k=2}^{mn} kP(\text{cross|N=k})P(\text{hasn't crossed before})$.
For $k=2$, the probability that two distinct edges cross is $\frac{{m\choose 2}{n\choose 2}}{mn\choose 2}=\frac{(m-1)(n-1)}{2(mn-1)}$, using the number of edge crossings for the previous question. However, in general it's unclear how to solve for $P(\text{cross})$ given that it depends on which edge was selected and the values of m and n (e.g. topmost and bottommost edges will never cross, whereas an edge in the middle is more likely to).

Your question does not seem to be formulated very precisely. Say your formula under the spoiler for $m=n=2$ gives 1, but a complete bipartite graph $K_{2,2}$ is a square and it has no intersections of edges outside vertices. If $m=3, n=2$, your formula gives 3, but the graph $K_{3,2}$ can be drawn in the plane such that there are no intersections of edges outside vertices. Etc. You need to clarify your question.

@kabenyuk A standard way to draw complete bipartite graphs is two draw each bipartition on vertical lines parallel to each other. In this way, $K_2,2$ does have a crossing.

@MathieuRundström
I don't think this is the standard way. Still waiting for clarification from the author of the question.

@kabenyuk yes the graph should be drawn with m nodes on one side and n on the other, with all edges between the two lines, as shown on Wikipedia on the top right
